# one out of three bootstrap 3 popovers is offset vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, offset, popover

Ok, I've searched all over the interweb prior to ask ;-) here it goes:

I have a bootstrap3 website with a sticky footer containing 3 pseudo links to trigger the popovers:

working

[image: working]

working

[image: working]

not working

[image: not working]

As you can see the third one is offset.
It's the only one containing html so that must be the cause

Here's the footer's rendered code:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" id="popo_vers" class="text-muted credit pull-left  text-center" data-toggle="popover" data-content="&lt;h4&gt;xxx&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;img src='/sites/5379f65f74fe729da1000003/theme/images/logo_spr_web_icon.png'/&gt;&lt;h4&gt;xxxxx&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;img src='/sites/5379f65f74fe729da1000003/theme/images/xxx_sm.png'/&gt;" data-original-title="Credits" data-placement="top" data-html="true">XXXX - v1.0 © 2014 Xxxxxxx</a>
    <a href="#" id="popo_aide" class="text-muted credit pull-right text-center" data-toggle="popover" data-content="azer@azer.com Fond&nbsp;du&nbsp;couloir&nbsp;à&nbsp;droite" data-original-title="Besoin d'aide?" data-placement="top">&nbsp;aide</a>
    <a href="#" id="popo_lega" class="text-muted credit pull-right text-center" data-toggle="popover" data-content="blahblah" data-original-title="Mentions légales" data-placement="top">mentions légales • </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the js trigger:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

Please let me know if you need more info (can't fiddle it right now, it's a rails site with lots of includes). Thx

Comment: There must be something in your CSS that is causing the problem, eg overruling the popover behavior. The provided code works right away -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZDx4S/

Comment: If I replace the missing images with placeholdit images it is offset again. Still investigating ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without fiddle, you can try to set the container to the body:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: 'body'
});
```

From the [Bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage):

> Appends the popover to a specific element. Example: container:
>   'body'.  This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to
>   position the popover in the flow of the document near the triggering
>   element
>   - which will prevent the popover from floating away from the triggering element during a window resize.